# How to prove $\prod_{n = 1}^{N} (1 - \frac{a}{n^k}) \geq 1 - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{a}{n^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

How to prove (or maybe disprove?) the inequality that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $a \in (0, 1)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\prod_{n = 1}^{N} (1 - \frac{a}{n^k}) \geq 1 - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} \frac{a}{n^k}
\end{align*}

This looks a bit like Bernoulli's inequality

Comment: One possible way is to use induction on $N$.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more general, for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in [0, 1]$ you have
$$
\prod_{n = 1}^{N} (1 - a_n) \geq 1 - \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n
$$
and that can easily be proved by induction on $N$ (as already mentioned
in a comment).

Your special case follows by setting $a_n = \frac{a}{n^k}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of the general version of *Bernoulli's inequality*:

> For any $a_1,\dots a_n >-1$, having all the same sign, we have
>   $$(1+a_1)\dotsm(1+a_n)\ge 1+a_1+\dots+a_n. $$